# Cannot make CustomView for UIViewRepresentable to work correctly in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have this SwiftUI component

```
var body: some View {
    let image = TypographyImage.image(for: typography, kind: kind)
    let width = image.size.width + 4
    let height = TypographyImage.height(for: typography) * (kind == .oneLine ? 1.0 : 2.0)

    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                    .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .top))
                    .offset(y: TypographyImage.offset(for: typography))
                    .background(Color.red)
            if isSwiftUI {
                Text(text)
                        .typography(typography, theme: AmityTheme.shared)
                        .background(Color.red)
            } else {
                MyUILabel(text: text, typography: typography, theme: AmityTheme.shared).background(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which display this UI

[image]

Notice that in `MyUILabel`, I apply background red color.
The background color and alignment of `MyUILabel` inside `HStack` is display correctly when in `MyUILabel` I return a `UILabel` as first child view

As show below

```
struct MyUILabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
    var typography: AmityTheme.Typography
    var theme: AmityTheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let view = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        updateUIView(view, context: context)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: UILabel, context: Context) {
        view.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: theme.textAttributes(for: typography, palette: .black))
    }
}
```

However, if I change it to return my custom view like

```
struct MyUILabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
    var typography: AmityTheme.Typography
    var theme: AmityTheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PaddedUILabel {
        let view = PaddedUILabel(frame: .zero)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        updateUIView(view, context: context)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: PaddedUILabel, context: Context) {
        view.update(text: text, typography: typography, theme: theme)
    }
}

class PaddedUILabel: UIView {
    private var label: UILabel!
    private var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        self.label = label

        addSubview(label)

        topConstraint = label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
        bottomConstraint = label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            topConstraint,
            bottomConstraint
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

    func update(text: String, typography: AmityTheme.Typography, theme: AmityTheme) {
        let attributes = theme.textAttributes(for: typography, palette: .black)
        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    }
}
```

The result is

[image]

The background color is gone and `HStack` center vertical alignment is not respect. I can't seem to know why this happening.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are using custom view PaddedUILabel (UILabel) ?

Comment: Since this is a kind of a central framework for our app and I have to make sure Our theme with NSAttributedString work correctly for both SwiftUI and UIKit. The `PaddedUILabel` is gonna be implement on Framework side to make displaying text with exactly the same as designer intended (`NSAttributedString`'s key property is not enough). That's why `PaddedUILabel` is made

Answer (score 1):

Seem like layout any constraint within `CustomView` and make it `UIViewRepresentable` will not work according to [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/mm8wjq/can_autolayout_constraints_even_be_used_in/gtpy3ex?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> In SwiftUI, parent asks child: what size do you want to be? Child tells parent, and parent sets size. Done.
> AutoLayout however, needs more than one pass to determine the complete layout. It simply doesn't get that chance.

> My rule-of-thumb for UIViewRepresentable is: keep it SUPER DUPER simple and only wrap a single view. More than one view is asking for layout problems.

Also [this](https://losingfight.com/blog/2020/08/22/uiviewrepresentable-doesnt-respect-intrinsiccontentsize-invalidation/) states that there is a limitation on how SwiftUI layout work which incompatible with vanilla layout constraint and `intrinsincContentSize`